# How do I mock a class and control a returned value in py.test with pytest-mock?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to use `py.test` to test some code that does various `LDAP` searches, and modifications.

I'm using `pytest-mock`, but I'm having trouble understanding how to mock out the creation of the an LDAP object, and control what it returns when a `search_s()` is called on the mocked object.

I thought this would do what I wanted, but the test fails, the count shows the generator function `find_users()` never yields anything.

```
import pytest
# Here is some code to simply test mocking out ldap.initialize(), and
# controlling the return value from calls to search_s()
import ldap

def find_users(ldap_url, admin_user, admin_password, userbase):
    lobj = ldap.initialize(ldap_url)
    lobj.simple_bind_s(admin_user, admin_password)
    for i in lobj.search_s(userbase, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '*'):
        yield i[1]['uid'][0]

class TestMocking:

    @pytest.fixture()
    def no_ldap(self, mocker):
        return mocker.patch('ldap.initialize')


    def test_ad_one_user(self, no_ldap):
        # try and modify how search_s() would return
        no_ldap.search_s.return_value = ('', {'uid': ['happy times']})
        count = 0 
        for i in find_users('', '', '', ''):
            count += 1
            assert i=='happy times'
        assert count == 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use patch directly (and something was off about your structure):

```
from mock import patch, Mock
import pytest
# Here is some code to simply test mocking out ldap.initialize(), and
# controlling the return value from calls to search_s()
import ldap

def find_users(ldap_url, admin_user, admin_password, userbase):
    lobj = ldap.initialize(ldap_url)
    lobj.simple_bind_s(admin_user, admin_password)
    for i in lobj.search_s(userbase, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '*'):
        yield i[1]['uid'][0]

class TestMocking:

    @patch('ldap.initialize')
    def test_ad_one_user(self, no_ldap):
        # try and modify how search_s() would return
        data = [('', {'uid': ['happy times']})]
        search_s = Mock(return_value=data)
        no_ldap.return_value = Mock(search_s=search_s)
        count = 0
        for i in find_users('', '', '', ''):
            count += 1
            assert i=='happy times'
        assert count == 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @salparadise.  This one works, but I'm still confused, because I thought the py.test "way" was to use fixtures, so you could re-use them across tests.

Comment: @GeoffCrompton depends on your goal. fixtures allows scoping per module or test session, and by default only on a function (so exactly as this is doing), however you can also use unittest.TestCase and use a `setUp` function to initialize your patches for all the unittests in the class.

Comment: `You can just use patch directly` - is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @dm295 is this what you are after https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#nesting-patch-decorators

Comment: @salparadise thanks. I knew how to use `patch` with `unittests`. But I didn't know that it's possible to use with `pytest` as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be getting confused between https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html and pytest monkey patch. I don't think both behave in the same way.

You can make it work using mock patch
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

```
@pytest.fixture()
def no_ldap(self):
    patcher = mock.patch('ldap.initialize')
    patcher.start()
    yield patcher
    patcher.stop()
```

Comment: Nice. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50048692/456550) for a way to do the same thing by using patch() as a context manager.