# py.test patch on fixture

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I use the following to mock constant values for a test with py.test:

```
@patch('ConstantsModule.ConstantsClass.DELAY_TIME', 10)
def test_PowerUp():
    ...
    thing = Thing.Thing()
    assert thing.a == 1
```

This mocks DELAY_TIME as used in both the test, and in Thing, which is what I expected.

I wanted to do this for all the tests in this file, so I tried

```
@patch('ConstantsModule.ConstantsClass.DELAY_TIME', 10)
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def NoDelay():
    pass
```

But that doesn't seem to have the same effect.

Here is a similar question: [pytest-mock mocker in pytest fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43358802/pytest-mock-mocker-in-pytest-fixture), but the mock seems done in a non-decorator way there.

Answer (score 71):

I'd say patching via decorator is not the optimal approach here. I'd use the context manager:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def no_delay():
    with patch('ConstantsModule.ConstantsClass.DELAY_TIME', 10):
        yield
```

This way, patching is cleanly reverted on test teardown.

Comment: how can I pass in the delay time to this fixture from within a  test case?

Comment: Indirect parametrization allows you to give fixtures values to run over. https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization

Comment: this solution is very clean

Answer (score 17):

pytest provides builtin patching support via the [monkeypatch fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html).  So to patch the constant for all tests in the file you can create the following autouse fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def no_delay(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr(ConstantsModule.ConstantsClass, 'DELAY_TIME', 10)
```

If you don't want to have the `ConstantsModule` imported in your tests you can use a string, see the [full API reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch).

Comment: Beware that `monkeypatch` is a function-scoped fixture, so your test will raise a `ScopeMismatch`.

Comment: Whoops, that'll teach me for not testing the code I post.  Thanks for the heads up, I've corrected it.